# GET and POST methods using Slim and Twig

Tags: php, twig

I am trying to create a forum using the Slim PHP framework. However, I have run into the issue of assigning parameters for each section of the forum. I want to get an id for each category toilets the topics. This would mean the url would be something like:

```
http://website.com/forum?catID=1
```

Based on that the page would render the topics for that category. I have been using the `urlFor()` function, but i cannot seem to figure out to 
pass that into it.

Here is my current route code:

```
$app->get('/forum', function() use($app) {

$categories = $app->categories->get();
$topics = $app->topics->get();


$app->render('forum/forumCat.php', ['categories' => $categories, 'topics' => $topics]);
})->name('forumCategories');
```

and for the code i use to display the categories:

```
{% for category in categories %}
<br>
<p><a href="#">{{category.category_title}}<a><br>{{category.category_description}}</p>
<br>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are `categories` and `topics` variables that you defined?  If you just want to get the value of `catID`, you can access it like this:

```
$catID = $app->request->get()['catID'];
```

You might also consider putting the catID in the URL itself, something like `http://website.com/forum/category/1`.

Then you could retrieve it like this:

```
$app->get('/forum/category/:cat_id/?', function($cat_id) use($app) {

    $topics = functionToLookUpTopicsByCategoryID($cat_id);

    $app->render('forum/forumCat.php', [
        'topics' => $topics
    ]);
})->name('forumCategories');
```

If you want to catch the category id from a `POST` request, you can do something like:

```
$app->post('/forum/category/?', function() use($app) {
    $id = $app->request->post()['id'];
    ...
});
```

Comment: I defined them. But what about posting the catID

Comment: What do you mean, post?  You want to send it to the template?

Comment: So that the link would have catID=1 and then from there you can get catID=1 to list the topics

Comment: If catID=1 then that can be pulled from the url so that every topic with a catID of 1 is listed, whereas if the catID was 2 in the url then every topic with a catID of 2 would be listed

Comment: Right, I get that.  But how does your software model categories and topics?  In a database, I presume?

Comment: Ah yes. I was wondering how I would post the catID to the end of the url so I can get it

Comment: Which url?  Are you talking about the **file path** to your template?

Comment: http://url.com/forum?catID=1 which would occur when the user clicks on the category(which is a link) so it would take them to the page with the topics

Comment: Yes I get that.  That is what my answer shows you how to do.

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but how do you pass 1,2,3 or whatever the cat_id is into that :cat_id. I understand how you GET is, not how you POST it. Would you maybe pass it in using the urlFor() function?

Comment: Are you asking how to *generate* a POST request, or how to *catch* a POST request?  Also, you should modify your question so we don't leave a long comment trail.

Comment: Ok will modify. And I was asking both. Sorry for the confusion